# Subtracting or adding lists of lists in prolog?

Tags: list, prolog

I am fairly new to prolog and am trying to mess around with lists of lists. I am curious on how to add two lists of lists or subtract them resulting in one list of list. If I have two lists of lists lets say,

```
SomeList = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]  
SomeList2 = [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]]
```

How could I add or subtract `SomeList` and `SomeList2` to create a list of lists? Resulting in a sum of say

```
sumList([[2,4,6,8],[10,12,14,16]])
```

or vice-versa for subtraction? Any help would be appreciated not looking for code but for insight !

Comment: You mean *elementwise* addition?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest approach is with [`maplist`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=maplist/4):

```
add(X, Y, Z) :- Z is X + Y.

op_lists(L1, L2, R) :-
    maplist(maplist(add), L1, L2, R).
```

Which gives:

```
| ?- op_lists([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], R).

R = [[2,4,6,8],[10,12,14,16]]

yes
| ?-
```

In the expression:

```
maplist(maplist(add), L1, L2, R).
```

`maplist(G, L1, L2, R)` calls `G` on each element of `L1` and `L2`, resulting in each element of `R`. Since each element of `L1` and `L2` is a list, then `G` in this case is `maplist(add)` which calls `add` on each element of the sublists.

You can obviously modify `add(X, Y, Z)` to be whatever operation you wish on each pair of elements. You can also make the addition more "relational" by using CLP(FD):

```
add(X, Y, Z) :- Z #= X + Y.
```

Then you also get, for example:

```
| ?- op_lists([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], L, [[3,6,9,12],[10,12,14,16]]).

L = [[2,4,6,8],[5,6,7,8]]

yes
| ?-
```

If you wanted to do this without `maplist`, you could still use `add/3` and use a two-layer approach:

```
op_lists([], [], []).
op_lists([LX|LXs], [LY|LYs], [LR|LRs]) :-
    op_elements(LX, LY, LR),
    op_lists(LXs, LYs, LRs).

op_elements([], [], []).
op_elements([X|Xs], [Y|Ys], [R|Rs]) :-
    add(X, Y, R),
    op_elements(Xs, Ys, Rs).
```

You can see the simple list processing pattern here, which the use of `maplist` takes care of for you.

Comment: Thank you so much !

Answer (score 4):

Besides the solutions presented by @lurker (+1), I would also add the possibility to use DCGs, since you are working on lists. For the available operations I suggest to define a slightly more general predicate opfd/4 instead of add/3. Here are exemplary rules for addition and subtraction as asked in your question, you can use these as templates to add other two-place arithmetic operations:

```
opfd(+,X,Y,Z) :-
   Z #= X+Y.
opfd(-,X,Y,Z) :-
   Z #= X-Y.
```

As the desired operation is an argument, you only need one DCG-rule to cover all operations (marked as (1) at the corresponding goal). This way, of course, you have to specify the desired operation as an argument in your relation and pass it on to the DCGs. The structure of these DCGs is very similar to the last solution presented by @lurker, except that the resulting list does not appear as an argument since that is what the DCGs describe. For easier comparison I will stick with the names op_lists//3 and op_elements//3, the calling predicate shall be called lists_op_results/4:

```
lists_op_results(L1,L2,Op,Rs) :-
   phrase(op_lists(Op,L1,L2),Rs).

op_lists(_Op,[],[]) -->
   [].
op_lists(Op,[X|Xs],[Y|Ys]) -->
   {phrase(op_elements(Op,X,Y),Rs)},
   [Rs],
   op_lists(Op,Xs,Ys).

op_elements(_Op,[],[]) -->
   [].
op_elements(Op,[X|Xs],[Y|Ys]) -->
   {opfd(Op,X,Y,R)},                    % <-(1)
   [R],
   op_elements(Op,Xs,Ys).
```

Example queries:

```
   ?- lists_op_results([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], +, R).
R = [[2,4,6,8],[10,12,14,16]]
   ?- lists_op_results([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], [[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], -, R).
R = [[0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0]]
```

@lurker's example:

```
   ?- lists_op_results([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], L, +, [[3,6,9,12],[10,12,14,16]]).
L = [[2,4,6,8],[5,6,7,8]]
```

You can also ask if there is an operation that fits the given lists:

```
   ?- lists_op_results([[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], L, Op, [[3,6,9,12],[10,12,14,16]]).
L = [[2,4,6,8],[5,6,7,8]],
Op = + ? ;
L = [[-2,-4,-6,-8],[-5,-6,-7,-8]],
Op = -
```

On a sidenote: Since the operation is the first argument of opfd/4 you can also use it with maplist as suggested in @lurker's first solution. You just have to pass it lacking the last three arguments:

```
   ?- maplist(maplist(opfd(Op)),[[1,2,3,4],[5,6,7,8]], L, [[3,6,9,12],[10,12,14,16]]).
L = [[2,4,6,8],[5,6,7,8]],
Op = + ? ;
L = [[-2,-4,-6,-8],[-5,-6,-7,-8]],
Op = -
```

Comment: Nice generalisation, s(X). However, `op/4` is a somewhat misleading as it parallels `op/3`... maybe adding something to the name along the lines of `z` or `fd`, etc. could help.

Comment: @repeat: That's a good point. I changed the predicate name to opfd/4. I think that reflects the use of clpfd better than appending *z*. Thanks for the hint :-)

Comment: `signop(Sign, X, Y, Z) :- Z #= X+ Sign*Z.`

Comment: .. maybe add `Sign in -1 \/ 1`

Comment: @false: For addition and subtraction your suggestion is indeed much more elegant than opfd/4 in my proposal. However, when proposing the generalization I had the ulterior motive of providing a template that can be used to add other operations like `*` or `mod` as well. Addition and subtraction just happen to be the examples the OP explicitly mentions in his question, so I stuck with those in my answer. :-)