# Substract elements from two lists | Prolog

Tags: prolog

How can i substract elements from one list with elements from other list? Something like this:

```
substract_lists(List1, List2, ListR) :- maplist(plus, List1, List2, ListR).
```

but for substract.

EDIT:
I'm tried with `ListR is List1 - List2` but it given me an error.

Comment: refer to similar question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38252848/subtracting-or-adding-lists-of-lists-in-prolog>

Comment: Replace `plus` with a predicate that subtracts two elements.

Answer (score 2):

Following the advice of Willem Van Onsem, the code is like this:

```
substract(A, B, R) :- R is A - B.
substract_lists(List1, List2, ListR) :- maplist(substract, List1, List2, ListR).
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that this is a homework problem, the instructor is probably looking for you to roll your own.

The one problem you'll have to consider is what happens when the two lists of are different lengths.

Here is one approach. I resolve the above problem by treating missing elements as being zero:

```
subtract( []     , []     , []     ) .
subtract( [A|As] , []     , [R|Rs] ) :- R is A-0, subtract(As,[],Rs).
subtract( []     , [B|Bs] , [R|Rs] ) :- R is 0-B, subtract([],Bs,Rs).
subtract( [A|As] , [B|Bs] , [R|Rs] ) :- R is A-B, subtract(As,Bs,Rs).
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also just flip the order for `plus`, since `plus(A, B, C)` gives `B is C - A` when both C and A are instantiated.

```
substract_lists(List1, List2, ListR) :- maplist(plus, List2, ListR, List1).
```